# fluent nhibernate error when converting 't' 'f' to boolean "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean."

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I've got a problem when getting a record from the database with a boolean column. I can't change the database structure.
The database type is Character(1) (PostgreSQL) where they used 't' for true and 'f' for false. I have used the PostgreSQLDialect.

I've tried to put this in the hibernate-configuration

```
 <property name="query.substitutions">1 't',0 'f'</property>
```

I've tried to override in the dialect

```
 public override string ToBooleanValueString(bool value)
        {
            return value ? "t" : "f";
        }
```

The mapping is:

```
Map(x => x.IsTemplate).Column("template_p");
```

Still not working,
Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have to create your own user type here.  Here is an example of creating your own:

http://lostechies.com/rayhouston/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype/

Your mapping would then become something like this:

```
Map(x => x.IsTemplate).Column("template_p").CustomType<MyCustomType>();
```

**Edit:**

You might also be able to use the standard YesNo type by doing something with your query-substitiutions.  I haven't tested this but maybe something like this:

```
<property name="query.substitutions">yes 't', no 'f'</property>
```

Your mapping would look pretty much the same as I stated above except you would use the YesNo type.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed Cole W, i made this customtype and it works like a charm
(source link: https://lostechies.com/rayhouston/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype/)

```
public class TFType : IUserType
{
    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public Type ReturnedType
    {
        get { return typeof(TFType); }
    }

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get { return new[]{NHibernateUtil.String.SqlType}; }
    }

    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        var obj = NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]);

        if(obj == null ) return null;

        var truefalse = (string) obj;

        if( truefalse != "t" && truefalse != "f" )
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Expected data to be 't' or 'f' but was '{0}'.", truefalse));

        return truefalse == "t";
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        if(value == null)
        {
            ((IDataParameter) cmd.Parameters[index]).Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            var yes = (bool) value;
            ((IDataParameter)cmd.Parameters[index]).Value = yes ? "t" : "f";
        }
    }

    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }

    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        return cached;
    }

    public object Disassemble(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        if( ReferenceEquals(x,y) ) return true;

        if( x == null || y == null ) return false;

        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        return x == null ? typeof(bool).GetHashCode() + 473 : x.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tou should have provided sourec attribution. Code is the same as in the article I just found, you have only changed truefalse<>yesno.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried, but maybe this could work:

```
Map(x => x.IsTemplate).Formula("case when template_p = 't' then 1 else 0 end")
```

Comment: This method would work as long as the property can be read-only. You will not be able to update fields mapped using Formula

Answer (score 0):

We are using postgres 8.3-8.4 with boolean values without any problems. However, when using ANTLR3 based HQL parser it started to get picky about boolean substitution, so we made our own dialect with the following override:

```
public override string ToBooleanValueString( bool value )
{
    return value ? "true" : "false";
}
```

However, we used NHibernate.Dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect, not the generic one. What postgres version are you running?

EDIT: Oh, sorry, I didn't follow that you hade a character(1) column. maybe this would help instead (with the quotes)?

```
return value ? "'t'" : "'f'";
```

Comment: The problem, I found out, is that the existing database (I may not change the datatypes) is using sometimes char(1) and sometimes boolean. So the solution of Cole W is working fluently.